# UISwitch didn't show in tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I want add 4 switch control to tableView, but only one show correctly.
Code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 1:{
            cell.textLabel.text=SetCellData[indexPath.section];
//            cell.accessoryView=_switchView;
//            UISwitch *switchView=[[UISwitch alloc]init];
//            cell.accessoryView=switchView;
            break;}
        case 2:{
            cell.textLabel.text=SetCellData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
//            UISwitch *switchView=[[UISwitch alloc]init];
//            switchView.tintColor=ColorWithRGB(52, 186, 253);
//            cell.accessoryView=switchView;
//            cell.accessoryView=self.switchView;
            break;}
        case 3:{
            cell.textLabel.text=SetCellData[indexPath.section];
            cell.accessoryView=_switchView;
            break;}
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

in case 1, if i use    `UISwitch *switchView=[[UISwitch alloc]init];cell.accessoryView=switchView;` it shows correct.
in case 2,  use `[[UISwitch alloc]init]` or `cell.accessoryView=_switchView;`,it didn't show.

UPDATE:[Projrct in Github](https://github.com/gshushu/tableVIew)

Comment: Use `[self.switchView copy];`

Comment: Design all cells as custom cells in Interface Builder and use the different cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` respectively.

Comment: @New16 it doesn't work and show 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'